# Using the .find() jquery function with a nodeList

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am having trouble with iterating over a nodeList to alter certain elements inside those nodes.
Here is the html:

```
 <div class="row one-dish-row dish1">
        <div class="dishes-container">
          <h4>Falafel</h4>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="prices-container">
          <h5></h5>L.L.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row one-dish-row dish2">
        <div class="dishes-container">
          <h4>Falafel</h4>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="prices-container">
          <h5></h5>L.L.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row one-dish-row dish3">
        <div class="dishes-container">
          <h4>Falafel</h4>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="prices-container">
          <h5></h5>L.L.
        </div>
      </div>
```

I created a nodeList (as an array) of all the elements with the class ".one-dish-row", and tried to access the h4 element within one of them to alter it. Here is the js:

```
  const dishNodeList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one-dish-row'));
    dishNodeList[1].find("h4").innerHtml = "Hello I am Ghadir";
```

It is not working ('Falafel' is not changing into 'Hello I am Ghadir'). I get the following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: dishNodeList[1].find is not a function.

I don't know what exactly is wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But you're not using the jQuery `find` here, you have a plain array and call `find` on a DOM Node

Comment: Are you actually looking for a jQuery solution or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: Any solution will be fine as long as I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make sure you're keeping track of which variables contain a HTMLCollection / NodeList, and which ones are jQuery Objects; because it will change which Methods you have access to.

jQuery [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is called from a jQuery Object, and you're using it on a NodeList; so instead of jQuery [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), you're trying to use Javascript [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

There's two approaches for this, if you're wanting to use jQuery Methods or Javascript methods

---

For jQuery, create your jQuery Object by wrapping in `$( )`, and then you can access the right Methods - use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to return the matching element ( still as a jQuery Object ) and [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to change the text of that Element

---

For Javascript, you can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) from your NodeList item to select down, and then edit the [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property to insert the text you want

```js
const dishNodeList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one-dish-row'));

// jQuery
$(dishNodeList[1]).find('h4').text('Hello I am Ghadir');

// JavaScript
dishNodeList[1].querySelector('h4').textContent = 'Hello I am Ghadir';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row one-dish-row dish1">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row one-dish-row dish2">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row one-dish-row dish3">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful, and your code the shortest, so I went with this. I need to do some more learning concerning all of javascript (so yes, I am confusing plain js with jQuery, thank you for the explanation).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things, you are using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and `innerHtml`:

1. First one can be used on arrays and need a function to find the elements and that's the reason why you got the error message, instead you should use [`getElementsByTagName('h4')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName),
2. There is a mistake with the name, you should use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead.

Like the following:

```js
const dishNodeList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one-dish-row'));
const h4Elements = dishNodeList[1].getElementsByTagName('h4');
const h4 = h4Elements[0];
h4.innerHTML = "Hello I am Ghadir";
```

```html
<div class="row one-dish-row dish1">
  <div class="dishes-container">
      <h4>Falafel</h4>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="prices-container">
      <h5></h5>L.L.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row one-dish-row dish2">
    <div class="dishes-container">
      <h4>Falafel</h4>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="prices-container">
      <h5></h5>L.L.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row one-dish-row dish3">
    <div class="dishes-container">
      <h4>Falafel</h4>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="prices-container">
      <h5></h5>L.L.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It seems I confused jQuery with vanilla javascript (I was under the impression we can do that). I haven't tried your solution as I went with another code suggested here, but I guess it is very similar and getElementsByTagName('h4') would work just the same. (Also VS Code was completing it as innerHtml - I don't know why.) Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is using .find().text() :

```js
$('.one-dish-row').eq(1).find("h4").text("Hello I am Ghadir")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row one-dish-row dish1">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row one-dish-row dish2">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row one-dish-row dish3">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>
```

DOM is using querySelector and innerHTML (spelling!!!) or textContent

```js
const dishNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.one-dish-row');
dishNodeList[1].querySelector("h4").textContent = "Hello I am Ghadir";
```

```html
<div class="row one-dish-row dish1">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row one-dish-row dish2">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row one-dish-row dish3">
  <div class="dishes-container">
    <h4>Falafel</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prices-container">
    <h5></h5>L.L.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the find method on a html collection (HTMLDivElement).

When you console.log ( h4Elements = dishNodeList[1].getElementsByTagName('h4'));
it returns null.
you will need to go down DOM tree one layer after another before you set the inner.HTML elements of h1 .

i have broken down this to you as below.

```
const dishNodeList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one-dish-row'));        
const dishNodeListOne = dishNodeList[1];        
const firstElchild = dishNodeListOne.firstElementChild;
const firstChildEl = firstElchild.firstElementChild;
 firstChildEl.innerHTML= 'Hello I am Ghadir';
```

Comment: I believe this would probably work though I haven't tried it - it is time consuming (that's what I wanted the find() function for). There is an answer below that works with a find() so I went with it (but anyway, thank you for the answer).